# feature extraction and dimension reduction with pca in opencv

Tags: opencv

```
//make every image as a row vector    
Mat data = formatImagesForPca(v);
//apply PCA
PCA pca(data, cv::Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, k);

//project in some kxk dimension    
Mat p = pca.project(data);
//calculate eigenvalues
Mat eigenval = pca.eigenvectors.clone();
```

i have applied pca but
i am facing problem in extracting the eigenvalues after applying pca.

i want to extract features using pca. but how can i reduce dimension and extract features and what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: Mat eigenval = pca.eigenvectors.clone(); ? seriously ?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/pca.cpp
http://www.bytefish.de/blog/pca_in_opencv/

I hope these code can help you.